# Throughput of TPL dataflow pipeline

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, google-cloud-pubsub, tpl-dataflow

We have a TPL dataflow pipeline with following blocks:

- Transform Block A: Http post call
- Transform  Block  B:  Database IO
- Transform Block C: Some unit conversion data (basically CPU intensive task)
- Transform Block D: Publish to Google PubSub
- Action Block E: Http post call

We are trying to run this pipeline with maximum throughput (100% CPU utilization). Things we have done:

•   Set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1000 to each block

•   Used `Semaphore` to limit maximum number of pipelines (which is 500 now)

•   Messages to first block in the pipeline are delivered by Google PubSub subscription (with Flow Control Setting = 100 as maxOutstandingElementCount)

Our results:

   13000 messages are processed in 2.5 hours (i.e., ~87 messages in 1 minute)

   100% CPU utilization

   450 thread counts

Now the question, can this performance be improved? We have requirement of 50,000 messages in 10 minutes (considering no data is fetched from the database in Block B). Or suggest the places where we should try to optimize our code.

Machine Used:

o   Procossor: Intel ® Xeon(R) CPU E3-1505M v5 @2.80GHz

o   RAM: 32 GB

o   System type: 64 bit OS

Comment: Did you try to decrease the number of parallelism to remove the thread starvation from too many simultaneous tasks?

Comment: yes, earlier we started of with no degree of parallelism. But I will reduce it and try again.

Comment: No degree means that they are sequential, which is not what you want. Try the number equal to the number of cores, which is the classic solution.

Comment: So its a 4 core machine, in Resource Monitor I see 8 cores which I am assuming is virtual cores.

Comment: You can try both values, but 500 is too much for that

Comment: Ok, my research says, the optimal value should be `Environment.ProcessCount` X 4.

Comment: Different researchs - different results. According my practice, you should select from: `{ Environment.ProcessCount +- 1, Environment.ProcessCount, Environment.ProcessCount * 2, Environment.ProcessCount * 4, Environment.ProcessCount / 2 }`, and measure it!

Answer (score 4):

You should optimize for max throughput regardless of CPU load, especially because you have mostly IO related work (http calls, file access, etc) where the CPU isn't used much anyway.

Parallelism should be a factor of the CPU cores you have available. The server cannot physically process more things at the same time than the number of cores so using a very large number of threads won't help. It's just creating more overhead for the same computing bandwidth and will actually slow everything down.

Parallelism for CPU-based work should be limited to the number of cores so that each core is working at full capacity but not overloaded. IO-based work is async and waiting for the IO to complete so it can use greater parallelism to dispatch more tasks at the same time.

A good start would be `(# of cores) x 4` for the IO blocks and `(# of cores)` for the CPU-intensive blocks. That means if you have 4 CPU cores available, use 4 for CPU blocks, and 16 for the IO blocks. Try that and scale up the parallelism on the IO blocks until you hit max throughput.

Also note that various settings in the Dataflow pipeline, like ensuring strict ordering, can be tweaked for more performance depending on your requirements. TPL Dataflow can easily process 100k+ items/second if properly configured.